# how managing pool on dexnet for test

Tags: dex

Good morning, I've successfully created a token on Solana and I'm now looking to explore liquidity pool options for testing purposes on devnet. Are there any DEXs on the Solana devnet that allow for the creation and management of liquidity pools? Specifically, does Raydium support this functionality on their devnet platform? Thank you for your assistance.